# Hide Form in C#

Tags: c#

I have a form in C# called `MainPanel` and a sub-form called `Login`. When the program starts, I want the `MainPanel` to load, but be disabled, and have the `Login` form to load, be at the front of the screen and active. My code for loading the `Login` form is shown:

```
Login l = new Login();
l.setParent(this);
l.Show();
l.BringToFront();
```

This code is in the function in `MainPanel`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and is being called, however, the `Login` form is not at the front. How do I force it to show at the front, be enabled, while keeping the `MainPanel` disabled (which I did by setting `enabled = false` which works fine)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using .ShowDialog() instead of .Show()